# Asp MVC solution structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture, entity-framework-6

I am just starting to use MVC and have opted to have my solution hold separate project for the database interactions and a project for UI (Hopefully an acceptable way to work). The UI references the BL, but the BL holds no reference to the UI. So for me to pass values to the BL I have had to set parameters as `dynamic` (example below), should this be avoided? If so why?(apart from the lack of intellisense).

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(MyActionViewModel vm)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(vm);
        }

        //pass formCollection to model to do stuff with
        int isSuccessful = ModelName.Insert(vm);
        return RedirectToAction(....);
    }
}

public partial class ModelName
{
    public static int Insert(dynamic theVm)
    {
        using (ModelEntities ctx = new ModelEntities ())
        {
            ModelName mn= new ModelName();
            mn.AddressLineOne = theVm.AddressLineOne;
            mn.AddressLineTwo = theVm.AddressLineTwo;

            ctx.TheTargetedEntity.Add(mn);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return mn.id;
        }
    }
}
```

A colleague has suggested that I should make an additional project that both the BL and the UI reference, so I am able to strongly type parameters that I pass (and avoid weak typing as much as possible). My problem with this is that, in this case it seems to introduce an unnecessary element to the solution.

Am I viewing this problem in an over simplistic way or is the suggestion over-complicating the issue or are we both missing something completely(we are both new to MVC, coming from web forms and the site will be small to medium sized site).

Comment: In the POST method, initialize an instance of the data model and map the view model properties to it, then save the data model.

Comment: Would that not then make my controller "fat"? I've read that should also be avoided.

Comment: I would definitely suggest same as your colleague, I consider it `very bad` practice to use `dynamic` for BL public API. Not sure why you're considering this unnecessary - you will still have strong decoupling between BL and UI.

Comment: Of course not. And as for 'fat' vs 'thin' controllers - that's a matter of opinion. But whats is bad practice is using dynamic and have database access inside you model

Comment: Thankyou. I will probably go with my colleagues advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of passing dynamic to BLL, its better to create a project for your models and put your models there, so the model library can be shared between UI and BLL, without breaking any rule and without making BLL dependent to UI.

Using dynamic the thing you will miss is not vs intellisense, it is working typed.

The structure of project will be:

- **Models Project** (Independent, contains only models)
- **BLL Project** (Has reference of Model, Contains data access and business logic)
- **UI Project** (Has referece of BLL, Has reference of Models, contains ViewModels, Controllers, Views)

Technically Models project can be merged in BLL without breaking the rules, but making them in a separate assembly has its benefits.

You should trade off between your time, budget, scale of project,.. to make a correct decision. But for start, those 3 layers are enough (while you can decrease theme to 2 layers).

Answer (score 1):

Your BL project should know nothing about UI, that's right. I think it's not a good idea use dynamic. You should transform your ViewModel object into a BL object. You can use AutoMapper to do it http://automapper.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should scrap using dynamic and go for a tighter defined parameter. For a start, it will make your intentions clearer when someone else is reading your code and when writing unit tests.

If you know which entity is being inserted then you can pass it as an argument explicitly. If you do not know which entity is being inserted then you could pass a base class or interface that is inherited by each of your entities. This class or interface would define the properties common to all entities that use it e.g.

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public partial class ModelName : BaseEntity
{ 
    //Properties unique to ModelName
}
```

You should write your mapping code outside of your model. You could create a separate, in between layer to do this if you would like to keep your controller thin.

Consider creating a separate class to house your entity operations rather than using static functions. It feels to me like using static methods here violates OO design. Creating this separate class will not require you to write much more code than you have but it will rearrange your code to look cleaner.

```
public class BusinessService()
{
    public int Insert(ModelName model)
    {
        ctx.TheTargetedEntity.Add(model);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return model.id;
    }
}

public class PresentationService()
{
    public int Insert(MyActionViewModel theVm)
    {
        ModelName mn = new ModelName();
        mn.AddressLineOne = theVm.AddressLineOne;
        mn.AddressLineTwo = theVm.AddressLineTwo;
        return businessService.Insert(mn);
    }
}
```

I would add project references as follows:
Controllers -> PresentationService -> BusinessService -> DB